# Oracle Forms Web.show_document not showing JSP

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, oracleforms

In one of our forms, we are calling the Web.Show_Document() wherein we pass a jsp file inside. However, the problem is that instead of JSP being translated into HTML page, the page shows the code inside the JSP.

Could this be caused by a Oracle Forms service that is not running? Or it can be other factors?

Thanks

*Sorry for I cannot post the an image neither the codes for it is for the client's protection.

Comment: can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Call that jsp with its full application url, eg. http://yourmachine:8080/yourapp.jsp then it will open that application.

But if you will give only jsp file name then it will show in browser with its code.